# How to make div remain formatted the same at different sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, transform

We have a Bootstrap Jumbotron with a background image, some text (h1 and p) and a call-to-action button and would like to be able to scale the image for different viewports, but to keep the formatting the same. So the div would be treated just like an image.

I've started this experiment here: https://codepen.io/Codewalker/pen/xxKRLBd and have experimented with transition and transform, but I can't get it to display properly. It keeps acting like a responsive div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1056/1424/562" alt="test" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="heroContent">
        <h1>Jumbotron H1 goes here</h1>
        <p class="pHero">
        This is the first line in the jumbotron.<br>
        The second line appears underneath the first line.
        </p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Chat With Us</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  max-width:1424px;
}
.heroContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The goal is for the entire div to essentially be treated like an image, where it all scales without changing format or layout.

Comment: Maybe it is better to make a div with a backgroundimage, then put hero-content div inside it with % relative width?

Comment: is this what you try to do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdbOGLX  how this works?  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding#Values  #percentage

Comment: @Rustyjim - Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @G-Cyr - That's close, but we'd like to incrementally scale the h1 and p text size as well. Unlike a responsive div, we're trying to make the div look exactly the same on a mobile device as it does on a desktop... just smaller. Thanks for the post.

Comment: you can give a look at `vw`,`vh`, or `vmin`/`vmax` value to resize `font-size`. If you use `calc()`, you can avoid it to become too big or too small . test updated : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdbOGLX resize window's width to see what it does. tune to your need `font-size` and `padding` for `.heroContent` . if that becomes closer :)

Comment: I could make an example later on, at work now. Still need one? Because the answer below looks good to me also. Sry for being slow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the brilliant CSS aspect ratio box trick. The basic idea takes advantage of a quirk in calculation of `padding-top` by the browser. If a percentage based value is used it will be relevant to the **width** not the height of the element like you might expect. Read more: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

For your layout, I simplified the markup so there is just an outer div (`.postcard`) and an inner div containing all the content (`.heroContent`).

The outer div gets `position: relative` because the inner div will be positioned absolutely. Then apply the aspect ratio trick like this:

```
.postcard {
  width: 1424px;
  padding-top: calc(562 / 1424 * 100%);
}
```

The `padding-top` property is calculating an aspect ratio by dividing the height by the width and then multiplying that ratio by 100% to get the correct height **relative to the width** (because it is padding-top). Now the outer container will always remain with that fixed height/width aspect ratio. Apply the image as a background to that div. Your inner content can be lined up to cover that area like this:

```
.heroContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

To offset the positioning of the content, take advantage of the same quirk of `padding-top`:

```
.heroContent {
  padding-top: 8%;
  padding-left: 8%;
}
```

Remember the `padding-top` is based off the width because the value is a percentage. Now you just need the content to scale with the div. To achieve that, assign `font-size` values relative to the viewport width:

```
.heroContent h1 {
  font-size: 3vw;
  margin-top: 0; /* this line removes the extra space you would get from default margin top on a heading element */
}

.pHero {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
}

.heroContent .btn {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

Run the snippet in full screen view and change the viewport width to see the effect. Hope that helps!

```css
.postcard {
  position: relative;
  width: 1424px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: calc(562 / 1424 * 100%);
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1056/1424/562');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.heroContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 8%;
  padding-left: 8%;
}

.heroContent h1 {
  font-size: 3vw;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.pHero {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
}

.heroContent .btn {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="postcard">
  <div class="heroContent">
    <h1>Jumbotron H1 goes here</h1>
    <p class="pHero">
      This is the first line in the jumbotron.<br> The second line appears underneath the first line.
    </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Chat With Us</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just about perfect. Thanks. For some reason, the background image isn't showing up in Firefox (Win10) for me.